# My first RF Transmitter Circuit

Tags: rf, 433mhz

I'm in the process of creating my first 433mhz RF transmitter with a PT2622 encoder & SAW Resonator.  I included a portion of my schematic below that shows my PT2622.

[image]

Does my schematic look correct or am I completely off?

This circuit is causing me a lot of headaches! I can't seem to find any examples online of one being used with a PT2622.  The PT2622 datasheet shows an example circuit (below)...but they use an LC circuit rather than a SAW...What could I "take out" of this example and replace with a SAW?

[image]

Comment: There is no chance that the 2n2222 will operate at that frequency. Also, where is the data input, where is the antenna, and where is the SAW resonator? You need to explain your circuit.

Comment: Sorry, i should have edited my schematic...I used 2n2222 as a placeholder in eagle.  I plan on using a MPSH10.  The SAW resonator is the circle with three outputs.

Comment: The antenna is between C7 and C8.  I planned on using a thicker trace here for the antenna.

Comment: I may be completely lost...

Comment: How a SAW resonator will provide 433 MHz? I am just curious, I did not understand.
edit: Got it! Apologies for such silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit is drawn in such an odd way that I cannot determine if it might work or not. Besides that, there are no component values so that makes it impossible to judge if it will work or not. I agree that a 2n2222 will not cut the mustard here. There are plenty 433 MHz transmitter schematics to be found when googling for them. Tip: search for "images" instead of "the web".

Regarding the PT2262, pin 17 is it's output, this output switches between 0 V and 12 V (the value of the supply voltage) where 12 V means: transmitter on, 0V means transmitter of.  So just use that pin 17 to switch the power to the transmitter on and off, just like in the example schematic in the datasheet.

I have a suggestion, why don't you just use a ready-made module like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/OZ-AC-433Mhz-RF-transmitter-link-kit-for-Arduino-ARM-MC-U-Remote-control-Sale-/171927089559?hash=item2807a73197:g:SCMAAOSwuTxV8U-b) ?